# Force Android to display "Desktop Version" when you add to home screen

Tags: google-play-store, 5.0-lollipop, chrome-for-android

I view several websites only as "Desktop Versions" but when I add them to my home screen they do not respect this decision.

Is there any way to force this feature to work correctly?

Comment: Which browser? With Chrome if you create shortcut when the site is in desktop mode, the shortcut on home screen also opens up in desktop mode

Comment: @beeshyams not for 5.0 android

Comment: @beeshyams no it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Yes . install kiwi browser and from kiwi browser settings turn on only desktop site option and create home screen shortcuts from kiwi

Comment: This does not work for messenger.com

Comment: @William  turn on desktop site first, then open www.facebook.com instead of m.facebook.com and start messeger from facebook...

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't work for messenger.com?

Comment: @William im afraid i dont